# Track by $index in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to implement different dates using datepicker in my application. I have a checkbox box if user checks that check box then am adding the dates.
But it seems track by index is not working.

Here is my code-

```
<div class="form-group">       
   <label>6. Enter Onsite Details( Up to 4)</label> <br>
      <div ng-repeat="selecting in selects track by $index" >
          <div class="datePicker">  
              <button 
                 bs-datepicker 
                 class="btn btn-info" id="comm_cal_bttn"
                 name="date"
                 data-animation="am-flip-x"
                 data-autoclose="true"

                 ng-blur="getMinTime(index);"
                 ng-model="selects[index].commDate">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Date
               </button>
               &nbsp;
               <p ng-show="selects[index].commDate">
                  {{selects[index].commDate}} <span class="text-muted"> {{selects[index].commDate}}</span> {{combinedTime.format('h:mm A')}}
               </p>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="addMore(keyAdd);" ng-model="keyAdd"> 
          <label for="dateCheck">Add Additional</label>

</form>
```

above code on selecting a date am calling a function `getMinTime(index)` but index is showing undefined in my controller.

My controller-

```
$scope.selects = [{commDate : null}];
$scope.getMinTime = function(index){

// here index is showing undefined
}
```

I want to perform some operation based on the index value. Suppose I added 4 dates. What am I doing here here? Any suggestion?

Comment: try to pass `$index` instead of `index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$index` as a parameter not `index`

```
<!-- other code -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label>6. Enter Onsite Details( Up to 4)</label>
  <br>
  <div ng-repeat="selecting in selects track by $index">
    <div class="datePicker">
      <button bs-datepicker class="btn btn-info" id="comm_cal_bttn" name="date" data-animation="am-flip-x" data-autoclose="true" ng-blur="getMinTime($index);" ng-model="selects[$index].commDate">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Date
      </button>
      &nbsp;
      <p ng-show="selects[$index].commDate">
        {{selects[$index].commDate}} <span class="text-muted"> {{selects[$index].commDate}}</span> {{combinedTime.format('h:mm A')}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="addMore(keyAdd);" ng-model="keyAdd">
    <label for="dateCheck">Add Additional</label>

    <!-- other code -->
```

Comment: aaaah. my bad. Thanks alot. I will accept the answer in 10 minutes